# How to pass variables in python flask to mysqldb?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Code in .py file:

```py
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
# Check if this user had voted for somebody
is_voted = cur.execute("SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME="+str(session["username"]))
```

`session["username"]` keep a user cookie. The user I already logged in names "admin"

But there might be something wrong with the MySQL command inside is_voted

Error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'")
```

But I got the correct return value while using

```
SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='admin'
```

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my input format inside is_voted?

Comment: `is_voted=cur.execute("SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME= ?",(session["username"]))` , can you try this and let me know the result

Comment: Another error happens when using this line. Error：```MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting```

Comment: then the parameter needs to be converted to string, `is_voted=cur.execute("SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME= ?",str((session["username"])))`

Comment: It still gets error, but the following answer```is_voted = cur.execute("SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='%s'" % str(session["username"]))``` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output string of the combination `"SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME="+str(session["username"])` misses couple of single quote `''`. You can change it to:

```py
is_voted = cur.execute("SELECT TUTOR_VOTED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='%s'" % str(session["username"]))
```

Comment: This will surely the better answer but its sort of open to attacks.[SQLinjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Yeah, sure that's it's not the best practice for code in production. But I think it's a different story as some cases people may like to see result as quick as possible

Comment: Thank you so much, I really don't know this kind of attack. Should I write a function to check the username to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: It is a long story. You can find some ideas here https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md