# How to pass multiple variables in python flask to mysqldb?

Tags: flask-mysql

I have tried to apply the advice in this question but I still don't seem to get the code to work. I am trying to pass two variables

[How to pass variables in python flask to mysqldb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980081/how-to-pass-variables-in-python-flask-to-mysqldb)

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
for row in jdict:
  headline = row['title']
  url = row['url']
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO headlinetitles (Title, Url) VALUES ('%s','%s');",str(headline),str(url))
mysql.connection.commit()
```

I get the error TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Maybe this will help someone.

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
for row in jdict:
    headline = row['title']
    url = row['url']
    sqldata = ("INSERT INTO headlinetitles (Title, Url) VALUES ('%s','%s');",str(headline),str(url))
    cur.execute = (sqldata)
mysql.connection.commit()
```